# Equivalent of C++'s std::istringstream in Rust

Tags: rust

In C++ I can a convert a string to token stream using `std::istringstream`. How to do the same in Rust?

C++

```cpp
std::string data;
std::getline(file_handle, data);

if ((data.empty()) || (data.front() == '#'))
    continue;

std::string ctype, name;
int class;

std::istringstream iss(data);
iss >> ctype >> name >> class;
```

Comment: Rust doesn't have an equivalence of C++ streams, so there is also no equivalent to `istringstream`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman can you guide me how to extract individual data which are separated by whitespace

Comment: `str::split_whitespace` might be useful.

Comment: The easiest way is to `string.split_whitespace()` and iterate over that. More advanced use-cases can be solved by writing a parser. [`nom`](https://docs.rs/nom) is an excellent parser combinator library.

Comment: What level of equivalence are you looking for? Parsing? Simple whitespace splitting? The  latter is already covered by the various `.split*` functions (e.g. [`split_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split_whitespace)), and `.parse` will work if the types its parsing to are annotated, but it's not quite the condensed "split *and* parse as a semi-one-liner" C++ gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A vaguely similar version of:

```cpp
std::string ctype, name;
int class;

std::istringstream iss(data);
iss >> ctype >> name >> class;
```

in Rust would look something like this (in real code, `unwrap`s would likely be `?` usage or `expect` calls with useful errors or error-handling in some other manner):

```rust
let mut tokens = data.split_whitespace();
let ctype = tokens.next().unwrap();
let name = tokens.next().unwrap();
let class: i32 = tokens.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap();
```

As a note, `split_whitespace` is producing `str` sub-views of `data`, not independent owned `String`s, so you may want to add `.to_owned()` calls for `ctype` and `name` if `data` will expire before they do.

Answer (score 3):

I think `split_whitespace` is what you want. Here's a Rust equivalent of your code snippet.

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::path::Path;
use std::str::FromStr;

let file_path = Path::new("your_path_to_file");
let file_handle = File::open(&file_path).expect("couldn't open file");
let reader = io::BufReader::new(file_handle);

for line in reader.lines() {
    let data = line.expect("unable to read line");

    if data.is_empty() || data.chars().next().unwrap() == '#' {
        continue;
    }

    let mut iter = data.split_whitespace();
    let ctype = iter.next().expect("expected ctype");
    let name = iter.next().expect("expected name");
    let class_str = iter.next().expect("expected class");

    let class = i32::from_str(class_str).expect("class is not a valid integer");
}
```